# In a void-returning function, why would you return a void expression instead of omitting the return statement?

Tags: c++, return, void

Consider the following snippet:

```
void Foo()
{
  // ...
}

void Bar()
{
  return Foo();
}
```

What is a legitimate reason to use the above in C++ as opposed to the more common approach:

```
void Foo()
{
  // ...
}

void Bar()
{
  Foo();

  // no more expressions -- i.e., implicit return here
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably no use in your example, but there are some situations where it's difficult to deal with `void` in template code, and I expect this rule helps with that sometimes. Very contrived example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T retval() {
    return T();
}

template <>
void retval() {
    return;
}

template <>
int retval() {
    return 23;
}

template <typename T>
T do_something() {
    std::cout << "doing something\n";
}

template <typename T>
T do_something_and_return() {
    do_something<T>();
    return retval<T>();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << do_something_and_return<int>() << "\n";
    std::cout << do_something_and_return<void*>() << "\n";
    do_something_and_return<void>();
}
```

Note that only `main` has to cope with the fact that in the `void` case there's nothing to return from `retval` . The intermediate function `do_something_and_return` is generic.

Of course this only gets you so far - if `do_something_and_return` wanted, in the normal case, to store `retval` in a variable and do something with it before returning, then you'd still be in trouble - you'd have to specialize (or overload) `do_something_and_return` for void.

Comment: Thanks. All the answers were good, but this one illustrated the point nicely.

Answer (score 9):

This is a rather useless construction that serves no purpose, unless it is used with templates. That is, if you have defined template functions that returns a value that may be 'void'.

Comment: then it's hardly "useless", is it? ;)

Comment: @jalf: Well, in the form it is shown in the question it is pretty useless, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: true enough. I interpreted the code in the question as an example of the language feature, and asking when the language feature *in general* is useful. But fair point. ;)

Answer (score 7):

You would use it in generic code, where the return value of Foo() is unknown or subject to change. Consider:

```
template<typename Foo, typename T> T Bar(Foo f) {
    return f();
}
```

In this case, Bar is valid for void, but is also valid should the return type change. However, if it merely called f, then this code would break if T was non-void. Using the return f(); syntax guarantees preservation of the return value of Foo() if one exists, AND allows for void().

In addition, explicitly returning is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 4):

Templates:

```
template <typename T, typename R>
R some_kind_of_wrapper(R (*func)(T), T t)
{
   /* Do something interesting to t */
   return func(t);
}

int func1(int i) { /* ... */ return i; }

void func2(const std::string& str) { /* ... */ }

int main()
{
   int i = some_kind_of_wrapper(&func1, 42);

   some_kind_of_wrapper(&func2, "Hello, World!");

   return 0;
}
```

Without being able to return void, the `return func(t)` in the template would not work when it was asked to wrap `func2`.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of is if you had a long list of `return Foo();` statements in a switch and wanted to make it more compact.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a case where `Foo()` originally returned a value, but was later changed to `void`, and the person who updated it just didn't think very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, returning `void` can be helpful when writing templates.
You typically don't do it if you know that a function returns `void`, but it's helpful that it's legal:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename F>
auto apply(T x, F f) {
    // if f returns void, the return type of apply is deduced to void, and the following
    // return statement is legal
    return f(x);
}
```

This example may be a bit artificial, but in practice, returning `void` simplifies the implementation of [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply).

Another use case is making `switch` statements more compact:

```cpp
void one(), two(), three();

void before(int x) {
    switch (x) {
    case 1:
        one();
        break;
    case 2:
        one();
        break;
    case 3:
        one();
        break;
    }
}

void after(int x) {
    switch (x) {
    case 1: return one();
    case 2: return two();
    case 3: return three();
    }
}
```

Technically, `before` could also have just one line per case, but putting multiple statements on a single line often conflicts with style guides and/or auto-formatters.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is returning memory like math.h always returns. math.h has no void and no empty arguments. There are many practical situations where you need memory.

Comment: What? The math functions take arguments and return values because that's what they need to do to be math functions...